# How can we make list-group horizontal with Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

With Bootstrap 4, the list-group component is very rich with design aesthetics, such as with borders, background colors, rounded corners, etc..

With my following list...

```
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li class="list-inline-item align-top">item 1</li>
  <li class="list-inline-item align-top">item 2</li>
  <li class="list-inline-item align-top">item 3</li>
  <li class="list-inline-item align-top">item 4</li>
</ul>
```

...how can I make it look fancy like the following....

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">item 1</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">item 2</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">item 3</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">item 4</li>
</ul>
```

...and still keep it horizontal.

Comment: I don't follow, what is it you want to do exactly? if you want the block of code to look the same, why not use those classes?

Comment: I simply want a horizontal view of list-group items. list-group items in bs4 by default are stacked. Is there a natural way to make the adjustment (without hacking or depending on 3rd-party code)?

Comment: Oh, well, you would either have to adjust the style with other classes or override them yourself; or maybe use a different component like `button group`

Comment: That's my question  - what classes work in this situation? I've tried several different approaches, such as floating, inline-block, etc...but can't get list-group items to flex horizontally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the options you have to get it done involve overriding the styles in the classes with other classes, or using a different component that looks more like what you need like `Button Group` here you can see what I mean.

In the case you use `flex-row` to change the direction of the list-group, you would have to adjust the borders of each item so it looks as you need. In this case the list-group will flex horizontally on larger screens, but stack on smaller ones

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="list-group flex-md-row">
  <li class="list-group-item">item 1</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">item 2</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">item 3</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">item 4</li>
</ul>

<div class="btn-group rounded border" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Right</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I really like flex-md-row.  First time seeing that in action.

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of responsive utilities for flex items in Bootstrap 4, if any element you want to style is a flex-container or a flex-item you can use these classes https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/flex/

Comment: Bingo!  Responsive classes to flex direction is what I needed.  Many thanks for bringing this up!

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be using classes `d-flex` and `flex-row` on the `list-group`. If you want the items to stack on smaller screen, you can use the `breakpoint` classes of bootstrap (**SM**, **MD**, **LG**, **XL*). For example: `flex-sm-row`

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="list-group flex-sm-row">
  <li class="list-group-item">item 1</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">item 2</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">item 3</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This approach looks promising but they don't stack on a smaller width screen.  I still want it responsive on smaller devices.

Comment: actually `d-flex` is not needed as `list-group` is already a flex container

Comment: you can use breakpoint classes for stack on smaller screen, i'm going to update showing that...